# Why would EU governments push for a quick brexit?

Tags: european-union, brexit

European Commission President Jean-Claude Juncker is currently in the news for saying

> We now expect the United Kingdom government to give effect to this decision of the British people as soon as possible, however painful that process may be. Any delay would unnecessarily prolong uncertainty.

and statements from various specific nations back this up (at least France and The Netherlands).

What advantage is there to the EU to push this through right now? Wouldn't waiting for Scotland to make their moves and for a reelection be far more advantageous? A reelection could theoretically even mean the UK would stay (in the case that a party would make staying in the EU it's main campaigning point) and a more drawn out and careful process seems to be more advantageous to all parties economically. What am I missing?

Comment: To avoid nationalists to ask for referendum. And to avoid financial place to go down during an entire years, putting the entire Europe in recession (financial guys don't like incertitudes ;) )

Comment: "To avoid nationalists to ask for referendum" I don't get what you mean with that part. Uncertainty is definitely a bad thing, but isn't a rushed brexit even worse?

Comment: In France for example, our xenophobic/nationalist party, called the Front National, is already asking for a referendum (will never happen anyway). But the more time is passing, the more nationalist in EU countries will ask for it, creating instability in those countries.
UK will leave at minima in 3 months, said Mr Cameron, so no rush in fact.

Comment: Britain, as a member of the EU has a big say in many decisions the EU is going to make. On many issues the decision is taken by consensus, so having Britain part of the system is a compromise the other EU members have to make, but then they also benefit from Britain being part of the EU. But now that it is clear that Britain is going to leave, this makes it difficult to have Britain sit a the table in Brussels dealing with EU affairs.

Comment: I think the reasons are more economical. The economy hates uncertainty. It prevents investors from making investments. The earlier the UK makes up their mind about their future actions the better for the economy.

Comment: @GautierC I have a hard time believing that rushing this will result in less attention. It's gonna take around 2 years either way (this kind of stuff never takes less time than the deadlines), adding a couple of months to that with the potential for averting disaster would seem quite a reasonable deal.

Comment: @Philipp Economics thrives on uncertainty~ but I get where you come from, but the longer they take working out those deals, the less likely the UK will end up in a situation where there trade agreements are significantly worse than they are now (even if only transitionally as new agreements are in the works).

Comment: *"If it were done when 'tis done, then **'twere well, it were done quickly***" - Macbeth: Act 1, Scene 7

Comment: @DavidMulder investors abhor unnecessary risks, uncertainty is disruptive.

Answer (score 6):

The longer time is spent by the departure of the U.K. from the EU, the more this debate about the departure will be on the political radar of everybody which naturally makes the advocates of other "exits" more visible and important.

If the U.K. is fully removed from the EU soon, the EU officials may try to quickly restore the old "business-as-usual" pretending that nothing serious has happened, no changes in the EU are necessary, the U.K. has de facto never belonged to the EU so it's not a big deal, and the EU should continue along the pre-Brexit path.

It's similar to a boyfriend who is rejected by a girlfriend and wants to stay active. He may want to get rid of the memories as soon as possible because they may prevent him from finding a new girlfriend etc.

This is probably how the EU officials are really thinking ([Merkel seems to be an exception](http://www.itv.com/news/story/2016-06-25/merkel-calms-calls-for-quick-brexit-process-after-referendum/), doesn't insist on speed) but it's highly disputable whether this strategy is realistic. There is a widespread opinion that the EU simply cannot continue along the same path towards ever deeper integration and ever greater arrogance of power that we observed before the referendum.

Everyone has realized how strong the voters in many countries actually are and that the Euroskepticism is very real. It is reasonable to expect that this newly discovered power of the Euroskeptics won't be forgotten. The Brits have created a precedent that won't go away. So in practice, it doesn't really matter how quickly the U.K. leaves the union.

In practice, the departure could be and should be much faster than David Cameron wants to suggest. The negotiations about the dissolution of Czechoslovakia only began after elections in mid 1992 and everything was absolutely ready by the end of the year 1992 – in less than 6 months – and new countries were fully created on January 1st, 1993. The exodus of cash from Slovakia caused concerns so the currencies had to be divided as well, just 6 weeks later, and it basically took just days of instant planning.

Czechoslovakia was a single country – the U.K. is just "vaguely affiliated" through the EU. So the U.K. departure could be expected to be simpler, not harder, than the Czechoslovak Velvet Divorce.

Comment: Czechoslovakia separated just after the fall of communism, at that time it was not yet well integrated in international organizations. Take e.g. the WTO, Slovakia became a member in 1995. But Britain is only an "indirect" member via the EU. For Britain to become a member after Brexit would require quite some work  http://www.cnbc.com/2016/06/24/reuters-america-wto-chief-says-ready-to-help-uk-and-eu-after-brexit-vote.html

Comment: While the addressed problem is real, I doubt that this answer really holds true. Clarity and certainty are needed - would you want to wait until the UK government makes up its mind whether or not they will ignore the referendum? A drawn out exit serves neither side. The moment the exit-negotiations start, the UK vote in EU matters can be treated differently.

Comment: Yes, if I were a European politician on the EU side of negotiations, I would surely allow the British to decide whether they want to ignite the article 50 and when. It's really their internal issue whether they want to ignore the referendum or take it into account, and how quickly. The situation is clear enough. There is now a people's decision that they want Brexit - and nothing else. This makes the U.K. somewhat unreliable or provisional EU member state but it's still a full member state, anyway. The EU laws make it clear that their membership must be respected at this moment - very clear.

Comment: And as MEP Zahradil pointed out, this is a decision that will influence years or decades or centuries to come. So trying to pretend that every 3 months are very important and pressure the U.K. to hurry up means to abandon their and our dignity.

Comment: @LubošMotl watching 3 months of tory- and labour- infighting will not help in the dignity matter. At the moment, EU parliament votes hinging on the UK would be awkward

Comment: The "infighting" is a part of democracy and people on my side of the barricade - those that naturally and instinctively oppose dictatorship, whether it's in Moscow, Berlin, or Brussel - *respect* it when people like you mock it and despise it. If the British system concludes that 3 or 10 extra months of internal political debates and battles is what's needed, then it is what's needed. Get used to the fact that you are not the dictator of Britain - even Queen Elizabeth has gotten used to it. My call is even more urgent if you're German and you seem to be.

Comment: Let me remind you that German and French people who tried to dictate the Britons what and when to do in the past - such as Napoleon, Adolf Hitler, and Wilhelm II - were assertively shown by the Brits that it's not their business. Isn't it a time for you to finally learn the lesson?

Comment: Of course it is part of a democracy, but it doesn't get us anywhere - I couldn't care less, who (personally) actually rules Britain, but *rule*, they should. Shirking away from that responsibility will only incite frustration. The UK no longer is the center of the world, but still too large to stay in limbo on such matters. The 3 months can be used productively - and the negotiation can take longer, but the decision to leave already happened.

Comment: Maybe democracy doesn't get *you*, Germans, anywhere, which is why you seem to be constantly thirsty to get your Hitlers and why the Parliamentary proceedings are for you, like for Hitler, just unproductive babbling. But democracy *has* gotten Britain quite somewhere - it became the main world empire at some moment and the cradle of capitalism. So why don't you modestly restrict your recommendations to the Hitlerjugend camps and allow the Brits to live according to their values? UK isn't a center of the world but it's still #2 source of visitors to my blog after US ahead of Germany.

Comment: Incidentally, I assure you that if you will be pleasing us - Czechia - with similar threats and propaganda when we will be leaving the EU, many Czechs will be eager to speed up things and kindly ask the Kremlin to use their weaponry and show you our disagreement with your interventions into our internal affairs. In 1938-1939, we waited for several years but maybe things could have been sped up.

Comment: In hindsight, the drawn out Brexit had exactly the opposite effect you predicted here. There were no follow-ups and pro-exit parties suffered at the polls, some even abandoned their exit rhetoric. https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/1369148119886213

Answer (score 6):

It's mainly because of the markets. The current situation is bad for the markets because of the uncertainties. The industry needs to know in what manner the UK-EU relationship continues (e.g will there be costums duties or a treaty of association). Until the new relations are not defined, the industry is not able to make long term predictions.

Comment: Which international investor in their right mind would invest in the UK now, when the future relationship with the EU is so uncertain? 2 years negotiations will be disruptive enough, 3 months added uncertainty do not help anyone.

Comment: People invest in China even though it isn't associated with the EU. Why should the association with the EU a necessary condition for an investor? Most investments won't be affected by the U.K.-EU relationships (almost) at all.

Comment: @LubošMotl China is a big, growing market with cheap labor. The UK is a medium market that has access to the EU market. If they leave, that access is lost and their importance is suddenly reduced, making the investment worth less.

Comment: It makes no sense, most businesses don't need any "access to the EU". To invest into the U.K. means to hire the Britons as the workers who do some job that needs to be done. What I, the investor, do with the products is up to me - so I had to have some markets to start with. Note that the EU only accounts for some 50% of British imports and exports and the percentage was going down recently. Also, the absolute size doesn't matter. One may equally invest to large, middle, and small countries. You're just inventing propaganda - but the Brits have said No to this propaganda. EU isn't essential.

Comment: @LubošMotl Of course they do. In China people know what to expect (even if the expectations and circumstances are not the best); But if one wants to make investments in the U.K. one cannot say what they have to expect after the exit; nobody can say how the conditions to make trade with continental Europe will have changed after the exit. For now, only two things are certain: 1.) the conditions will change, 2.) no one knows how they will  change. Even a dictatorial regime offers better conditions.

Comment: Nobody knows the exact future but the ignorance generally cuts both ways. It may be stupid to invest in the U.K. given some unknown events in the future, but it may also be stupid *not* to invest in the U.K. for the very same reasons. You may want to know exactly what happens but it's impossible - but the ignorance doesn't product particular answers about business decisions. It implies that business decisions carry an extra risk. The Brits have the right to create this uncertainty - better get used to it.